# How to forward gateway requests for a subnet through another connection under Linux

Tags: pptp, isc-dhcp, pptpd

I have a Debian machine acting as a DHCP server/NAT, connected via PPTP to another machine,connected to a subnet 10.0.0.0.  How do I configure it so requests from clients on this machine for the 10.0.0.0 subnet are forwarded over the PPTP connection?  Right now I can access any machine on that subnet from the server, but not from any DHCP clients.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add an entry for you routing table, I've broken this down [here](https://superuser.com/questions/531872/corporate-vpn-internet-traffic-tracing/532131#532131). Iptables should be installed if you don't have it installed already.

**Update**
An answer specific to linux is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/477730/mac-os-x-10-8-vpn-server-bypass-vpn-for-lan-traffic-routing-lan-traffic-to-sec/532792#532792)